# Can you list other ebay sellers items with the ebay api?

Tags: ebay-api

Is it possible to list items for sale by other eBay sellers using eBay API's (Trading, Browsing)?

I can only seem to list the ones in the environment I create in eBay developer program.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can list items of any user once you get the Auth & Auth token or the oAuth token from the eBayer.
Basically it is the same procedure yoi did to get the token, but the full one, not the simpliefied that you probably used.
In the developer website, in the token area there are instructions

Comment: Absolutely no.To use APIs you need a developer account and a token from the eBayer. The eBayer can be yourself or any other eBayer.  To get the token from an eBayer you have to follow the procedure that is explained in the documentation an d that is different if you use trading or REST APIs

Comment: Basically you have to build an url with parameters and pass it to the ebayer. He has to follow it and will be redirected to a page that seems  eBay loogin while is ebay authorization. He agree and ebay forward him to a page on your website where you save the token. Biut this is only the starting step.